# SOAP response attachment never received

Tags: java, soap, soapui, soap-client, saaj

We have a soap service(WSDL) which will return an attachment with the response. I was able to get the response using `SAAJ` client but no attachments got received. Please find the below code and screenshot of the `SOAPMessage` response object.

```
SOAPMessage soapResponse2 = soapConnection.call(msgRetrievalRequest(), url);
```

[image: SOAPMessage response object]

But when I try the same SOAP service through SoapUI attachments get received without any issue.

[image: SoapUI response]

**Can someone shed some light?**

Comment: You mean to send the attachment along with the request? And not receiving at server side?